# jison grammar definition leads to wrong token recognition

Tags: parsing, yacc, flex-lexer, jison

I recently found the project *jison* and modified the calculator example from its website. (http://zaach.github.io/jison/demos/calc/)

```
/* lexical grammar */
%lex
%%

"a"                   return 'TOKEN1'
"b"                   return 'TOKEN2'
<<EOF>>               return 'EOF'
.                     return 'INVALID'

/lex

%start letters

%% /* language grammar */

letters
    :
    | letters letter
    ;

letter
    : 'TOKEN1'
    | 'TOKEN2'
    ;
```

Parsing the string "aaabbbaaba" with a parser generated by the above grammar definition results in

```
Parse error on line 1:
aaabbbaaba
^
Expecting 'TOKEN1', 'TOKEN2', got 'INVALID'
```

Unfortunately I don't know why `TOKEN1` isn't found correctly. Having token INVALID removed I get the parse error

```
Unrecognized text.
```

I found the description of an association error, resulting in a similar error message, on [Issue with a Jison Grammar, Strange error from generate dparser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19980853/issue-with-a-jison-grammar-strange-error-from-generate-dparser) but I couldn't find something similar in my code.

What is a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question.

`jison`'s lexer generator has two modes: the default mode, and a slightly more `flex`-compatible mode. You select the latter by placing `%options flex` after the `%lex` line.

In default mode:

1. The first matching pattern wins, even if a later pattern would match a longer token; and
2. Patterns which end with a letter or digit have an implicit `\b` added to them, which limits the match to end on a word-boundary.

In `flex` mode, patterns are not altered, and the normal flex first-longest rule applies. However, the generated lexer will be slower (see below).

So in your lexer definition, `"a"` will not match the first <kbd>a</kbd> in the input string, because the generated lexer is actually trying to match `a\b` -- that is, an <kbd>a</kbd> followed by a word boundary.

You can workaround the issue by simply surrounding the pattern with parentheses:

```
("a")    { return 'TOKEN1'; }
```

or by using a character class instead of a quoted letter:

```
[a]      { return 'TOKEN1'; }
```

or by adding `%options flex` to your `%lex` section.

---

#### By way of an explanation

`jison`, unlike `flex`, does not build a single DFA lexer. Instead, it converts each lex pattern into an anchored javascript regular expression, and at each request for a token, it tries all the patterns until it finds the correct match.

To implement the `flex` first-longest match rule, the `jison`-generated lexer needs to try every regular expression for every token, because it can't know which is the longest match until it tries them all. The "first-match" rule can be quite a bit faster, particularly if common token patterns are put near the beginning of the file.

Unfortunately, the first-match rule is a lot harder to work with in the common case where a token might be a keyword or an identifier, and identifiers which happen to start with a keyword need to be matched as identifiers. With first-longest matching, it's sufficient to put the keyword first, since an identifier with a keyword prefix will be longer. But with first-match, it's necessary to limit the keywords or identifiers or both to end on a word-boundary.

Hence the combination of the two rules described above, which means that the normal pattern of listing the keywords before the `Identifier` pattern will still work. The word-boundary test prevents the keyword patterns from spurious prefix matches.

But if you have a lot of keywords, that is still a lot of patterns, even though most of them will fail quickly. So rather than using the `flex` convention:

```
"do"                         { return DO; }
"end"                        { return END; }
/* ... */
[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]_]*     { return "ID"; }
```

you're a lot better off making keywords represent themselves (as well as other fixed tokens, like operators), because that lets you combine all the keywords and multi-character operator patterns into a single regular expression:

```
/* Keywords and multicharacter operators in a single enormous pattern */
/* For jison mode, I added a manual \b because it won't be added 
 * automatically. In flex mode, that won't hurt, but it could be
 * removed.
 */
("do"|"else"|"end"|"if"|"then"|"while")\b|[<>!=]"=" { return yytext; }
[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]_]*                        { return "ID"; }
[[:digit:]]+("."[[:digit:]]*)?                  { return "NUMBER"; }
[[:space:]]+                                    ;
/* All single character tokens use a fallback rule */
.                                               { return yytext; }
```

#### The `<<EOF>>` rule

Many `jison` grammars have an explicit `<<EOF>>` lexical rule, which returns some token like `"EOF"` or `"END_OF_FILE"`. This token is recognized by an explicit augmented start production, which has `return` in its action:

```
%lex
%%
// ...
<<EOF>> { return "EOF"; }
/lex

%start input
%%
input: start EOF { return $1; }

start: /* The real start token */
```

This is a `jison`-specific idiom, which many would consider poor style in `flex/bison`. It allows the generated grammar to return an actual value, which is the result of the parse.

Don't just add the `<<EOF>>` rule to the lexical rules. If you supply your own `EOF` token, you are responsible for recognizing it in the parser. If the parser has no rule which matches the `EOF` token, the parse will fail.